# Why the Django extended user model is not able to show pre-populated data in while updating the fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I have written a program to update the User default fields(email with the help of UserCreationForm) and Extended User models(DOB, country etc). Below is the function:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def editUserProfile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)  # default user profile update
        obj = UserProfile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)  # custom User fields.
        form1 = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)

        if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
            obj.Photo = form1.cleaned_data['Photo']
            obj.dob = form1.cleaned_data['dob']
            obj.country = form1.cleaned_data['country']
            obj.State = form1.cleaned_data['State']
            obj.District = form1.cleaned_data['District']
            obj.phone = form1.cleaned_data['phone']
            form.save()
            form1.save()
            messages.success(request, f'updated successfully')
            return redirect('/profile1')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = UserProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        form1 = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, "authenticate\\editProfilePage.html", {'form': form, 'form1': form1})
```

With the help of above method I am able to update the user data. However, the issue is when I click on the "update" button on my profile page the next page that I get to enter new data to the fields doesn't come with pre-populated data. i.e, the "email" field has the pre-populated data, but the custom fields like (country, dob, state) are blank, ideally it they should have existing data showing to the user after the user click on the "update" button from the profile page.

Any idea. I hope  I was able to explain. Please let me know if any other query(s).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the same form:

```
form  = UserProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
form1 = UserProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
```

`email` and the custom fields are in 2 separate forms.

**2nd solution:**

Try:

```
default_data_profile = UserProfileForm.objects.get(user=obj)
form1 = UserProfileForm(initial = default_data_profile, instance=obj)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing, I have made the modification and updated  the main post. However the issue remains. The fields are still empty on clicking the "update" button.

Comment: No, It didn't work either. After adding your suggestion, inside the "if" I also added 
"default_data_profile.Photo = form1.cleaned_data['Photo']". Not sure if that was the right modification.
for "obj" its throwing "unresolved reference" error.  Thank you

Comment: `form1.cleaned_data['Photo']"` is not available outside the `POST` loop.  My code refers to the `GET` loop

Comment: I am working with it, will let you know of any outcome. Thank you for your time though.